# Reading socket reply in loop

Tags: c++, sockets

I have:

```
char buf[320];

read(soc, buf, sizeof(buf));
//print buf;
```

However, sometimes the reply is much bigger then 320 characters, so I'm trying to run the read in a loop to avoid taking up too much memory space. I tried read(soc, buf, sizeof(buf)) but that only prints the same first x characters over again. How would I print the leftover characters that did not fit into the first 320 characters in a loop?

Thanks

Comment: while(read(soc, buf, sizeof(buf)))
  printf("Reply: %s\n", buf);

Comment: is this linux or unix?  read() returns -1 on error which will still evaluate to true, so check for read == -1.  Also you need to null terminate your buffer one byte beyond where you read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loop to something like:

```
int numread;

while(1) {
    if ((numread = read(soc, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (numread == 0)
       break;

    buf[numread] = '\0';

    printf("Reply: %s\n", buf);
}
```

for the reasons Nikola states.

Comment: Better make the read() call take sizeof(buf)-1 instead of sizeof(buf), or that null-terminator byte that gets written just before the printf is going to be written after the end of the array... that would be a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  Never code and watch Terminator movies at the same time.

Comment: @Duck: I tried your code but I can't get it to work. My code stops at the read that will return 0 as a result so the loop would break. Not stop as in crash but stop as in loop forever. Did you try this? Is there something that is obviously wrong here? Is it possible I opened the socket with the wrong options?

Comment: @Emil - A blast from the past.  I changed one of the parens on the read but it looks ok otherwise.  A return of 0 means the other endpoint disconnected - maybe you are just waiting on a socket that closed?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `read( s, buf, buf_size )` the kernel copies `min( buf_size, bytes_available )` into the `buf`, where `bytes_available` is the number of bytes already received and waiting in *socket receive buffer*. The `read(2)` system call returns the number of bytes placed into application buffer, or `-1` on error, or `0` to signal `EOF`, i.e. a `close(2)` of the socket on the sending end. Thus when you reuse the buffer, only part of it might be overwritten with new data. Also note that `-1` evaluates to `true` in C and C++. This is probably the case you are hitting.

`printf(3)` expects *zero-terminated string* for the `%s` format specifier. The bytes read from the socket might not contain the `'\0'` byte, thus letting `printf(3)` print till it finds zero further down somewhere. This might lead to [buffer overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overrun).

The points here are:

1. Always check the value returned from `read(2)`

   If you print strings read from a socket - always zero-terminate them manually.

Hope this helps.